# get file from input to text file

Tags: php, text, input, save

i´m trying to get the info from my form input boxes in to a txt file. 
when i hit submit the variable do not come up in tje url bar and it do not save it to the txt file.. 
can somebody help me ? :)

here are the link to the site:

http://thom239u.keaweb.dk/quiz/minquiz.php

```
$deltager = file_get_contents("deltager.txt");

if(isset($_GET["name"])){
    $fornavn = $_GET["fornavn"];
    $efternavn = $_GET["efternavn"];
    $mail = $_GET["mail"];
    $deltager .= "<h3>" . "Navn: " . $fornavn . " " . $efternavn . "</h3>"."<p>" . "E-mail: ". $mail . "<br>" ."**************************" . "\n"; 
    $liste = file_put_contents("deltager.txt", $deltager);
}


        <form action="minquiz.php" method="GET" id="form">
            <input type="radio" id="svar" name="by" value=1>København <br>
            <input type="radio" id="svar1" name="by" value=2>Århus <br><br>

            <input type="text" name="fornavn" id="fornavn" placeholder="Fornavn" required=""><br>
            <input type="text" name="efternavn" id="efternavn" placeholder="Efternavn" required=""><br>
            <input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" placeholder="E-mail" required=""><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Send">
        </form>
```

Comment: check out the method attribute of your form

Comment: <form action="minquiz.php" method="GET" id="form"> ??

Comment: hmm no.. 
but it do not save the info from the input boxes... when i submit i write this in the console: 

event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: I got that using your form:

Tillykke gfdg dfgsfg det var rigtigt, held og lykke i vores lodtrækning
vil du vide mere om vores produkt så klik her

So it submits...

Comment: can you post your code with form?

Comment: Your inputs don't  have value tag...

<input type="text" name="fornavn" id="fornavn" placeholder="Fornavn" required="">

Tha's the problem

Comment: that is what i should do to.. 
but also save the data in 

http://thom239u.keaweb.dk/quiz/deltager.txt

Comment: i past the form in also..

Answer (score 0):

Your inputs don't don't have values...

```
<input type="text" name="fornavn" id="fornavn" placeholder="Fornavn" required="">
```

becomes

```
<input type="text" name="fornavn" value="" id="fornavn" placeholder="Fornavn" required>
```

EDIT

Use fwrite(file, text) instead

Comment: i just add the value to my input´s but it didn't help.. :S

Comment: Please explain what doesn't work. Is the form submitted? Does the code enclosed in the if statement run?

Comment: when a user type there info in the input, i should save the info in the deltager.txt file.. but it do not work

Answer (score 0):

Don't use

```
$deltager = file_get_contents("deltager.txt");//Don't use
```

Use

```
$deltager='';
if(isset($_GET["name"])){
$fornavn = $_GET["fornavn"];
$efternavn = $_GET["efternavn"];
$mail = $_GET["mail"];
$deltager .= "<h3>" . "Navn: " . $fornavn . " " . $efternavn . "</h3>"."<p>" . "E-mail: ". $mail . "<br>" ."**************************" . "\n"; 

$liste =file_put_contents("deltager.txt", $deltager, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
```

// using the FILE_APPEND flag to append the content to the end of the file

// and the LOCK_EX flag to prevent anyone else writing to the file at the same time

https://www.php.net/function.file-put-contents

Comment: i get a error in the line with $liste = fileput_contents(,);

Comment: it won't work.. :P
have you tried my link ?
after typing the info the hit submit shouldn't the value appear i the url line??